# syntax error - missing operator - in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am asked to do the following:

Create a new table, named sec0902_employees, that adds two new columns to the l_employees table.

Create the new columns by using the following row functions:

**Column Name:** full_name

**Access:** first_name & ' ' & last_name

**Column Name:** new_credit_limit

**Access:** credit_limit + 10.00

Here is my code:

```
select l_employees.*, 
first_name & ‘ ‘ & last_name as full_name,
credit_limit as new_credit_limit + 10.00
into sec0902_employees
from l_employees;
```

This is the error:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ‘first_name & ‘ ‘ & last_name as full_name’

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the original l_employees table:

[image]

Thank you for any assistance you can provide :-)

Comment: Your are missing a comma.  This is simply a typographical error.

Comment: is `‘` a valid quote in access ? Try using a normal quote, `'`

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean:

```
(credit_limit + 10.00) as new_credit_limit
```

the alias of the new column is `new_credit_limit` 
and it consists of the value of `credit_limit` + `10.00` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! :-) This is the code that worked:

select l_employees.*, 
first_name & ' ' & last_name as full_name,
(credit_limit + 10.00) as new_credit_limit
into sec0902_employees
from l_employees;

[image]